# How to sort a list based on the order of another list?

Tags: matlab, sorting

I need To sort values of a list based on the order of another list **without a loop**. For Example:

```
 A=[1 2 3 4 5] 

 B=[8 5 6 2 10 3 1 9 4]
```

Result for sorting `A` based on the order of values in `B` is:

```
 C=[5 2 3 1 4]
```

Comment: Will the numbers in `A` and `B` always be unique? Will all the numbers in `A` always be in `B`?

Comment: yes all the numbers in A always there in B.

Comment: And can there be repeated numbers?

Comment: No... just unique values that all exist in B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question needs clarity on many points such as will the numbers in `A` and `B` always be unique? Will all the numbers in `A` always be in `B`. But to get your `C` from your `A` and `B` you can do:

```
B(ismember(B,A))
```

If `A` is unique but `B` is not e.g.:

```
 A=[1 2 3 4 5] 
 B=[8 5 5 6 3 2 10 3 1 9 4]
```

then you need to change it to

```
unique(B(ismember(B,A)),'stable')
```

Comment: thanks, Both A and B have unique values and all the numbers in A exist in B and also A is always sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5]
B = [8 5 6 2 10 3 1 9 4]
m = 1;

C = zeros(size(A))
for n =1:length(B)
    if B(n) <= length(A)
        C(m) = A(B(n));
        m = m + 1;
    end
end

C
```

Comment: Does using `A(B(n))` not make the assumption that `A` is always going to be consecutive integers starting at `1`? What if `A = [2 3 4 5 6]`, does your solution still hold?

Comment: No, it doesn't. it will work even with A = [2 3 4 5 6] as well.

Comment: >> testss

A =

     2     3     4     5     6


B =

     8     5     6     2    10     3     1     9     4


C =

     0     0     0     0     0


C =

     6     3     4     2     5

Comment: For your test case, the result should have been `C = [5 6 2 3 4]` so your solution does not hold in this case. Rather check if the number is in `A` instead of using the number in `B` to index a number in `A`

Comment: Is this what he wants? I wrote the code with ethe intention of getting [6 3 4 2 5]. Anyways, it can be adjusted to compare value rather then picking up based in index.

Comment: Fair enough, the question was very ambiguous. I now how you were interpreting it.

Comment: Yup, even I was amazed to see how you interpreted it... really ambiguous question:)